# Python 3.x "Return" Statement Error

Tags: python, python-3.x

## RMS Function

```
def rms(x,counter):
   total = math.sqrt((float(x)/counter)
   return total
```

Above is my code for a simple function but I keep receiving a syntax error of:

```
return total
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax.
```

Why? I am sorry if this is a simple solution but please help. I'm running python 3.5.

Comment: you're missing a closing paren: `math.sqrt((float(x)/counter)`

Comment: You're missing a right parenthesis `)` on the preceding line.

Comment: Welcome to the marvelous world of computer science where errors are not where you think they are.

Answer (score 1):

You've got unbalanced parens:

```
math.sqrt((float(x)/counter)
```

Should be

```
math.sqrt(float(x)/counter)
```